# REGEX : How do I match/select specific links via Regex

Tags: regex, string

I don't know such information about Regex. I want to select all links which I give examples of below.

```
http://example.com/file/3843732a6e531/filename.rar
http://example.com/file/24af962a61126/filename.zip
http://example.com/file/3843732a6e531/filename-part1.rar
```

So I want to select all links which start with `http://example.com` and end with `.rar` or `.zip`

Comment: This should be easy. Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: No, as I said I am not professional on regex. And sorry for my bad English. Waiting for answers. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is the regex and some explanations:

```
^http:\/\/domain\.com(.*)\.(?:zip|rar)$
```

`^` is to say that it needs to start by ...

`http:` is litteraly matching `http:` (and it's case sensitive)

We want to match the 2 `//` of the link now, but `/` is a delimiter in Regex, so you need to escape it by putting a `\` in front of the character you want to escape

That's why we have `\/\/`

We want to match the `.` of the domain name. But as `/`, `.` already means **any character** in regex, so we need to escape it too.
That's why we have `\.`

You wanted it to check that the link ended with .zip or .rar.
That's been done with

```
(?:zip|rar)
```

Comment: Thanks you for these wonderful informations. I tried but it doesnt select. Any idea? : https://regex101.com/r/qY0yZ0/1

Comment: It's because you keep `^` and `$` while you are trying on text where what you want to select is in the middle of the text.
Remove them and it should work !

Comment: Or make the search multi-line and global - [check it here].(https://regex101.com/r/jJ8mF0/1)

Comment: But it selects this parts : "/file/24af962a61126/filename" and "/file/3843732a6e531/filename-part1" . I want to select all links which start and end with strings I said in my first question

Comment: An user answered and deleted his own message. His codes work but I dont know why he deleted his answer. His code : https://regex101.com/r/rV9cO6/2

Comment: sorry, it's because you need to add `?:` in `(.*)`.
Something inside ( ) is a selector, you select the part you want from the string. But that's not what we want. To tell it's not a selection, you need to put `?:` ! So here is the final regex: `^http:\/\/domain\.com(?:.*)\.(?:zip|rar)$`

Comment: Sorry I couldnt succed. Can you please give me demo link? Thanks you, and really sorry for my bad English and regex knowledge.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dS7lE8/1

you probably forgot to put the options `g` and `m` which are respectively : global and multi lines.

Comment: But it still doesnt find/match any result which you gave demo :(

Comment: If there are two links in same line, this would not separate. I'd at least use [`\S*` instead of `(?:.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/dS7lE8/3)

Comment: Thanks you for your replies. I figured out thanks to your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Regex:

```
(http:\/\/domain\.com\/.*?(?:rar|zip))
```

Here is the description at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hP0aD7/1).

Comment: Thanks you for your replies. I figured out thanks to your answers :)